# Hibernate won't save entity with a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `admin_log` (
  `LOG_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `USER_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `CREATION_DATE` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `ACTION` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `DETAILS` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`LOG_ID`),
  KEY `ADMIN_LOG_FK1` (`USER_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `ADMIN_LOG_FK1` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `user_master` (`USER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And here are my entities:

```
@Entity
@Table ( name = "admin_log" )
public class AdminLog {

    private Long            logId;
    private UserMaster      user;
    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy = IDENTITY )
    @Column ( name = "LOG_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20 )
    public Long getLogId () {
        return logId;
    }

    public void setLogId ( Long logId ) {
        this.logId = logId;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn ( name = "USER_ID" )
    public UserMaster getUser () {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser ( UserMaster user ) {
        this.user = user;
    }
    ...
}


@Entity
@Table ( name = "user_master" )
public class UserMaster {

    private Long        userId;
    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue ( strategy = IDENTITY )
    @Column ( name = "USER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20 )
    public Long getUserId () {
        return this.userId;
    }

    public void setUserId ( Long userId ) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I try to save `AdminLog` using `save()` method from `HibernateTemplate` I get the following error:

```
SEVERE: Column 'USER_ID' cannot be null
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not insert [...AdminLog];
SQL [insert into admin_log (ACTION, CREATION_DATE, DETAILS, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)];
constraint [null] nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [...AdminLog]
```

The problem is that `userId` is most definitely NOT null! It's like Hibernate can't retrieve `userId` from `user` property in `AdminLog`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your user persisted before saving the admin log?

Comment: use @ManyToOne(.. cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE }) if you want to persit both in one call.

Comment: Can you show your test or sample code where you are setting the user property in AdminLog?  You say the UserMaster has an id, is this because you pulled the UserMaster from hibernate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to save a transient instance of `UserMaster`. If you have an `id` of the object then you should load it fist and set to `AdminLog` object before save.

Answer (score 1):

You have to persist `UserMaster` before you persist `AdminLog`